# How to find out what is at a location?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, location

Is there a way with the Google Maps API or any alternative to find out what is at a given location?

> Example: Which businesses are at latitude X and longitude Y?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the Places API Nearby search

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

For example, if I wonder what is the nearest cafe for coordinate 37.441541,-122.146082, I can execute the following request

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=37.441541%2C-122.146082&rankby=distance&type=cafe&key=YOUR_API_KEY

The first result is 'Casa Cowper - Not a Business' (place ID ChIJj6q3zD27j4ARNLjlL4hpbP0)

You can see it in Geocoder tool:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#place_id%3DChIJj6q3zD27j4ARNLjlL4hpbP0